# PHP Deserialize JSON array and Get object name

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, serialization

how to get the object name？ e.g： “XXX.HOSTNAME”

```
$json = '{
    "XXX.HOSTNAME": {
        "IP": "123.195.214.93",
        "IP6": "",
        "DOCUMENT_ROOT": "/home/public_html/",
        "U_DISK": "154",
        "U_BANDWIDTH": "0",
        "TPL": "default",
        "ALIAS": "www.org",
        "STATS": "",
        "STATS_USER": "",
        "SSL": "yes",
        "SSL_HOME": "same",
        "LETSENCRYPT": "yes",
        "FTP_USER": "",
        "FTP_PATH": "",
        "AUTH_USER": "",
        "BACKEND": "default",
        "PROXY": "default",
        "PROXY_EXT": "jpeg,m4v,mkv,mov,mpeg,mpg,wmv,exe",
        "SUSPENDED": "no",
        "TIME": "15:56:54",
        "DATE": "2023-03-04"
    }
}';
```

php beginner,I can get the subordinate properties, but I don't know how to get the name of the object ... ...

Comment: `array_key_first(json_decode($json, true));` https://3v4l.org/sf3CP

Comment: print_r(array_keys(json_decode($json, true)));

Comment: If there is more than one key, that will give you all of them in an array that you can loop over. For your sample data, with only one key, the code I suggested will give you the key with no further processing.